# What does the "name" of a Virtualbox Bridged adapter mean and what is its effect on the connection?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed a VM under OS/x that already had some engtries for Bridged Adapater (as shown in screenshot).  These entries were inherited from the creator of the VM.

Should I change them/ remove them? Do they have a direct effect on the networking configuration?

I am asking because the VM presently does not have eth0 connectvity working.

[image: Bridged adapter using unknown/unavailable connectors]

Answer (score 1):

The Name property lets you select which adapter on your host machine to bridge with.

Comment: How do I change/remove/add a named entry?

Comment: Not clear if you noticed from OP: those "names" have nothing to do with the adapters on MY machine.

Comment: @javadba: That's weird. I would have assumed that the list is automatically populated and when you import a machine it only remembers the type of adapter.